# Splitting a Dataframe not based on a string, but a value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe cut from a much larger dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Name': [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7],
        'Value': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Name    Value
0     5       1
1     5       2
2     6       1
3     6       2
4     7       1
5     7       2

Ideal Output:
    Name    Value  Value2
0     5       1      2
1     6       1      2
2     7       1      2
```

I need a way to split the dataframe into 2 separate dataframes based on the "Value" column.  The rows with '1' in the Value column and the rows with '2' in the Value column need to be split up.

The best/end goal solution is to have one Name with the 1 and 2 be separate columns in the same dataframe.  My idea so far is to split the two and combine them so the data is side by side all tracing back to a single Name.

Comment: Can you add your ideal output in your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by your Name column and aggregate your values into a `list`.

```
out = df.groupby('Name').agg(list).reset_index()
```

1. Use a `DataFrame` constructor to break the value and assign them back:

```
out[['Value1','Value2']] = pd.DataFrame(out.Value.tolist(), index= out.index)

>>> out.drop('Value',axis=1)

   Name  Value1  Value2
0     5       1       2
1     6       1       2
2     7       1       2
```

2. Use `pd.concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([out['Name'],
              pd.DataFrame(out["Value"].to_list(), columns=['Value1', 'Value2'])],
              axis=1)

   Name  Value1  Value2
0     5       1       2
1     6       1       2
2     7       1       2
```

---

**Complete code to answer your comments:**

Sample `DF`

```
data = {'Name': [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7],
        'Value': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Name  Value
0     5      1
1     5      2
2     6      1
3     6      2
4     7      1
5     7      2
```

Answer:

```
out = df.groupby('Name').agg(list).reset_index()
out[['Value1','Value2']] = pd.DataFrame(out.Value.tolist(), index= out.index)
out.drop('Value',axis=1)

   Name  Value1  Value2
0     5       1       2
1     6       1       2
2     7       1       2
```

**Additional columns:**

```
data = {'Name': [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7],
        'Value': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        'extra':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Value':list}).reset_index()
out[['Value1','Value2']] = pd.DataFrame(out.Value.tolist(), index= out.index)
out.drop('Value',axis=1,inplace=True)

result = pd.merge(df.drop('Value',axis=1),out,on='Name',how='left')

>>>result
 
   Name  extra  Value1  Value2
0     5      1       1       2
1     5      2       1       2
2     6      3       1       2
3     6      4       1       2
4     7      5       1       2
5     7      6       1       2
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a dataframe that has the correct Name but each column is a single list of the two pieces of data.

Comment: Did  you run the first command, and then one of the two choices?

Comment: For example, can you run the entire last block in my answer?

Comment: That is what I did and I am getting the lists as values instead of the values separated out.

Comment: Check out the last part of the answer. I just added your sample data which i run the code on, and the result. Can you give it another go? If it doesn't work, I suspect it has something to do with your pandas version

Comment: Works on that dataframe, must be something with the other columns I have in the current dataframe

Comment: Not quite sure. Perhaps you can split your dataframe and merge back then? Or perhaps you can add them in your sample data and I can have a look?

Comment: I realize it is working for the two "value" columns.  the issue is now all the other data in the rows are being put into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
>>> df
   Name  Value
0     5      1
1     5      2
2     6      1
3     6      2
4     7      1
5     7      2

>>> dfs = [d for _, d in df.groupby('Value')]

>>> dfs
[   Name  Value
 0     5      1
 2     6      1
 4     7      1,
    Name  Value
 1     5      2
 3     6      2
 5     7      2]

>>> dfs[0]
   Name  Value
0     5      1
2     6      1
4     7      1

>>> dfs[1]
   Name  Value
1     5      2
3     6      2
5     7      2
```